# Scripting creation of cogo polylines including curves

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, cogo

Is it possible to create polyline features from cogo type text files? I have some files that have survey type coordinates in them and they contain straight line segments as well as curves (defined by tangent, arc and radius).

i need to do this on hundreds of files so using the cogo toolbar in arcmap is not really an option.

i know that i can parse the text files into a table or spreadsheet of coordinates and values and if the lines were straight i could figure out how to create them.

My issue is with the curves. Is there anyway to create those using arcpy, arcobjects, or sql server spatial?

Comment: I don't know the details of scripting it. The [Traverse Format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Traverse_file_format/01m70000002q000000/), however, does have language/syntax for creating curves. I would assume if there is some way to create a line, there's some way to create a curve using a script. The issue is just passing the parameters. I don't see a way to call the Traverse tool from a script, which would be the easiest. But if the Traverse tool can do it, I'm sure there's a way.

Comment: I should also add that there are third party tools that do the same thing as the Traverse tool does - ET GeoTools and Tract Builder come to mind. So while I don't know the specifics, I do know there *is* a way to programmatically draw a traverse by passing the correct parameters that doesn't rely on internal, Esri only coding or tools.

Answer (score 2):

COGO is not a format I have ever used but a quick look at the ArcObjects API documentation threw up this interface [ICadastralCogoImporter](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ICadastralCogoImporter_Interface/001000000024000000/). May be this is what you need along with the [ICadastralImporter](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001000000042000000) interface? I would be surprised if *arcpy* expose these specialized interfaces.

Maybe someone else reading this has more experience?